# How do you connect to mysql server from within docker?

Tags: mysql, docker

I want to build a Docker container for my CI jobs. The container should have its own mysql server.

I started building off the mysql docker image, like this:

```
# Use Docker image from Dockerhub pre-build with mysql
FROM mysql:latest

# Update apt
RUN apt-get update -y

# install mysql server
RUN echo 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password root' | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo 'mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password root' | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo 'mysql-community-server mysql-server/default-auth-override select Use Legacy Authentication Method (Retain MySQL 5.x Compatibility)' | debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get install mysql-server -y

RUN echo 'show databases;' | mysql
```

but on the last line, it fails because it cannot connect to the mysql server.

```
 > [16/16] RUN echo 'show databases' | mysql:
#19 0.603 ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I assume this is because the mysql server is not running. If I change the last line to

```
RUN echo 'show databases;' | mysql --host=127.0.0.1
```

then I get a similar message:

```
#19 0.813 ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1:3306' (111)
```

I have tried using `service mysql start` and `systemctl start mysql` and `/etc/init.d/mysqld start`, but none of these work. How am I meant to start the mysql server and connect to it from the same Docker container?

I also have been trying with `docker run --rm -it mysql bash` and messing around interactively, but I can't get it to work that way either.

Comment: Why do you want to start a mysql database within the docker container? The data will most probably not stored persistently. This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: The [Docker Hub `mysql` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) has environment-variable settings for the root password and database names.

Comment: My 2 cents, you're trying to use a container like if it were a virtual machine or a full OS. What one usually does is to have one container per application.

Comment: For context, I am using this container to run CI jobs. I want a brand new environment each time. I don't want persistent data because I actually want the database to start fresh each time.

Comment: just using mysql docker image and pass your password when start mysql image when you run the CI. @nullromo I do not know why you package the mysql docker again.